# Undestanding mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, mongoose

Good morning,
I am having a problem with the creation of a cart field in the user object, to be more precise I defined a simple model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({

name:{
    type:String,
    required: true
},

cart:[

    {qty:{type:Number,required:true}},
    {product:{type:String,required:true}}
    ]
   });

   module.exports= mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

The unexpected behavior occurs when I try to insert data in the database using the model above:
If I send datas to the DB using the following code:

```
    const cart  = {product:'lamp', qty:4};

    const utente = new User({
    name:'mario',
    cart:cart
    
    });
    
    
    utente.save()
```

It will be saved like this:

_id:5f06e8140a3290711bb7681f
name:"mario"
**cart:Array
0:Object
_id:5f06e8140a3290711bb76820
qty:4**
__v:0

As you can see instead of getting a cart array that should contain a product key with the 'lamp'
value and a qty key with the value of 4, I get an array containing an _ID and a qty,  why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in the schema definition. Currently, you have defined two JSON objects in the cart array. Please try updating the schema as below to get the expected result as mentioned in the question

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  cart: [
    {
      qty: { type: Number, required: true },
      product: { type: String, required: true },
    },
  ],
});
```